# How to fix swiftmailer configuration in Symfony 3.4 project

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, symfony-3.4

I am using Swiftmailer in my Symfony 3.4 project.
I have programmed the following component to send mails:

```
class MailSender {

  private $mailer;

  public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer) {
      $this->mailer = $mailer;
  }


  public function sendMail($target, $subject, $content) {
      $message = (new \Swift_Message($subject))
      ->setFrom('***@gmail.com')        
      ->setTo($target)
      ->setBody($content, 'text/html');

      return $this->mailer->send($message);
  }

}
```

In my services.yml I have added:

```
AppBundle\Service\MailSender:
    arguments:
        $mailer: '@swiftmailer.mailer'
```

In my parameters.yml I have added:

```
parameters:
  mailer_transport: smtp
  mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
  mailer_user: ***@gmail.com
  mailer_password: ***
```

If I now start my server with php/bin console server:run and execute the sendMail method, unfortunately the mail doesn't get sent (although the mailer returns 1 as response).
The Symfony Profiler shows me the following error log:
Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. g185sm18205331wmf.30 - gsmtp "

What is rare is: If I construct the \Swift_Mailer object on my own in my TestCase, the mail indeed gets sent.

```
public function testSendMail() {
    // GIVEN
    $transport = (new \Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl'))
    ->setUsername('***@gmail.com')
    ->setPassword('***');
    $swiftMailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);
    $mailSender = new MailSender($swiftMailer);

    // WHEN
    $mailsSent = $mailSender->sendMail('***@t-online.de', 'testMail', 'The Mailsender works!');

    // THEN
    $this->assertEquals($mailsSent, 1);
}
```

Can anybody see why it doesn't work if I inject \Swift_Mailer as a service?

Comment: Did you allow your application in GMAIL? GMAIL will prevent your application to send any mail as long as it's not allowed.

Comment: Hello Preciel, are you refering to enable less secure apps? Because yes, it was already enabled. Thanks for the hint though!

Comment: Not sure if it's that, but the moment you tried to send an email with your app, Google should have sent you email telling you that the app was blocked and you should use an API key, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried this one from symfony documentation ? [How to Use Gmail to Send Emails](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/email/gmail.html)

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    # ...
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_user:     your_gmail_username
    mailer_password: your_gmail_password
```

```
# app/config/config_dev.yml
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    username:  '%mailer_user%'
    password:  '%mailer_password%'
```

Note that you should set your mailer_transport to **gmail not smtp**

Comment: Yes, that was the correct solution, I already had the configuration in the parameters.yml, but i also had to add it in the config_dev.yml. I'm a bit surprised, I thought it would be sufficient to have it in one place. Thanks a thousand times for the hint!

Comment: Ah, I overread that it would also be possible in the parameters.yml changing smtp to gmail. So it might have been suffient to do that.